# Powershell CSOM to change web part view

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powershell, csom

I have a number of sites where I need to update the view on a web part on the home page. I would like to accomplish this through PowerShell and CSOM. Unfortunately I can't find the property I need to change in the web part.

This is what I have so far:

```
$siteurl = "https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/sc/site"

Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:CommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:CommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:CommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll")

# Create Context
$creds = Get-PnPStoredCredential -Name SPOAdmin -Type PSCredential
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($creds.UserName, $creds.Password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

# Get Page
$PageUrl = "$SiteUrl/SitePages/Home.aspx"
$page = $Context.Web.GetFileByUrl($PageUrl)
$Context.Load($page)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$webpartmanager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$Context.Load($webpartmanager)

$webParts = $webpartmanager.WebParts
$Context.Load($webParts)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($webpart in $webparts){
    $Context.Load($webpart.WebPart.Properties)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    $propValues = $webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues
    #Write-Host "Webpart ID: "$webpart.Id
    if($propvalues.Title -eq "Briefcase Roles"){
        $webPartID = $webpart.ID
        #Write-Host "webpart found"
    }
}

$webpart = $webParts | Where-Object{$_.ID -eq $webPartID}
```

This let's me make changes to the web part I need to update. I know I can update it using something like

```
$webpart.WebPart.Properties["SelectedView"] = "All Items"
$WebPart.SaveWebPartChanges()
$Context.Load($webpart)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but SelectedView is not the correct property name.

Can anyone confirm what the property is for changing the Selected View? I want to force it to All Items.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vardhman mentioned, a local instance of the view is created. Now, that View has a particular GUID which is equal to the webpart definition's ID.

Using this GUID, you can get the local instance of the listview and modify its ViewQuery,Viewfields and other properties.

Here, I have also loaded the list and list views, so change them as per your requirement.

Try and modify the below code. Works at my end :

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:CommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:CommonProgramFiles\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")


#Site collection URL
$siteurl = "url of site collection"


$userName ="userName" 
$password ="password" 

#client context object and setting the credentials   
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)   

# convert password into secure string  
$securedpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force   

$clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securedpassword) 

$PageUrl = "$SiteUrl/SitePages/Home.aspx"
$page = $clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl($PageUrl)
$clientContext.Load($page)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

#load the list and all the list views
$list = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Briefcase Roles");
$clientContext.Load($list);
$clientContext.Load($list.Views);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

$webpartmanager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$clientContext.Load($webpartmanager)

$webParts = $webpartmanager.WebParts
$clientContext.Load($webParts)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($webpart in $webparts){
    $clientContext.Load($webpart.WebPart.Properties)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    $propValues = $webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues
    Write-Host "Webpart ID: "$webpart.ID
    if($propvalues["Title"] -eq "Briefcase Roles"){

        $webPartID = $webpart.ID

        Write-Host "webpart found"

        #view guid is the same as webpart definition id
        $listView = $list.Views.GetById($webpart.ID);

        $clientContext.Load($listView);
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        #remove all the viewfields
        $listView.ViewFields.RemoveAll();

        #internal name of the columns
        $array = @("Name", "ProjectRole");

        for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
            $listView.ViewFields.Add($array[$i]);
        }

        # changing the CAML query and setting other properties (strictly optional)      
        # $listView.ViewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Modified\' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
        # $listView.Paged = $true;
        # $listView.RowLimit = 100

        $listView.Update();
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a massive amount of work! The bounty is all yours!

Comment: Welcome ! Always ready to help ! Could you please accept it as answer, so it wont show up for us in the unanswered section ? Thanks !

Comment: Done - sorry, thought I had done that already!

Answer (score 1):

Once a view is selected, a local instance of the view is created in the webpart. This means that to set your view, you will have update the View XML directly in the webpart properties:

```
$webpart.WebPart.Properties["XmlDefinition"] = "<View>...</View>"; //XML of the All Items view
$WebPart.SaveWebPartChanges()
$Context.Load($webpart)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this yesterday, but the changes don't seem to save - I will try it again today.

Comment: Hi,

I have test this again, the changes do not get saved. I used the following:

$defn = $webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues.XmlDefinition
$defn = $defn.Replace('<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Name"/></ViewFields>','<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Name"/><FieldRef Name="ProjectRole"/></ViewFields>')
$webpart.WebPart.Properties["XmlDefinition"] = $defn
$WebPart.SaveWebPartChanges()
$Context.Load($webpart)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

However after running this, the new field is not visible. Getting the XMLDdefinition again returns the original, unchanged XMLDefinition