# List webpart not show all views of list SHP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part

I have to import so many views of a specific list (200+-) in SharePoint 2010.

I add the views to a wiki page with a web part list, but the web part list dropdown "Selected View" in the "Show Views" section of the Properties of the Web Part, doesn't show all the views, and i need to add all the views

How i can view all the views of the list? Or how i can add the WebPart views with CSOM? (I have certain knowledge in that, so if i can do that, since it is mechanical work it would be better).

The step to step of the work is:

- Add WebPart List
- Change the View of the list, the name of the WebPart and the audience
- Apply changes
- Add another and so on.

Thanks in advance boys, i love you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set audience for a list web par, you could refer to here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c3c78200-1649-4545-849e-b76689d38dfc/set-target-audience-for-list-view-web-part-using-powershell-csom?forum=sharepointgeneral

```
    $List = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName")
    $context.Load($List)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()


    $Pages = $List.RootFolder.Files
    $context.Load($Pages)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $Page = $Pages | Where {$_.Name -eq "ViewName"}
    $context.Load($Page)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()


    $WPM       = $Page.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared")
    $context.Load($WPM)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $WebParts = $WPM.WebParts
    $context.Load($WebParts)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $WebPart = $WebParts[0]
    $context.Load($WebPart)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $WebPart.WebPart.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = "My Group"

    $WebPart.SaveWebPartChanges();
    $context.Load($WebPart);
    $context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To change the view, here is a demo for your reference:

[Powershell CSOM to change web part view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221267/powershell-csom-to-change-web-part-view)